# Does there exist $F:[0, 1]^m\to [0, 1]^n$ which pushes forward Lebesgue measure to absolutely continuous measure?

Tags: probability-theory, analysis, measure-theory, pushforward

Suppose I have iid Uniform $[0, 1]$ random variable $U_i, 1\leq i\le m$. Let $n=m(m-1)/2$. I am interested in a measurable function $F:[0, 1]^m\to [0, 1]^n$ such that $Y:=F((U_i)_{i=1}^m)$ has absolutely continuous law with respect to $Leb_n$. I know that the answer to this question is affirmative, because $([0, 1]^m, Leb_m)$ and $([0, 1]^n, Leb_n)$ are equivalent. That is, there is a measure preserving isomorphism between these two spaces. If $F$ is such a measure preserving isomorphism, then the Law of $Y$ is simply $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measure on $[0, 1]^n$.

However, I am interested in a s special kind of function $F$. That is, I want $$F((U_i)_{1\leq I\leq m})=(f(U_i, U_j)_{1\leq i<j\leq m}),$$
for some function $f:[0, 1]^2\to \mathbb{R}$. The question is does there exist such a function $F$ so that $F((U_i)_{1\leq I\leq m})$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measure. (This is where it becomes important that $n=m(m-1)/2$.)

Comment: what means both sides of the identity $F((U_i)_{1\leq I\leq m})=(f(U_i, U_j)_{1\leq i<j\leq m})$? By now, as far as I understand you want some $F$ such that $F_* \lambda _m=\lambda _m \circ F^{-1}=\lambda _n$, but I dont understand your notation

Comment: I do not want $F_{*}\lambda_m=\lambda_n$ (but it would do the job). I want something (probably) weaker, that is, $F_{*}\lambda_m<<\lambda_n$. But the constraint is that I want $F$ to be of certain form. In particular, take $m=4$, then I want $F(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)=(f(x_1, x_2), f(x_1, x_3), f(x_1, x_4), f(x_2, x_3), (x_2, x_4), f(x_3, x_4))$ for some function $f$. Hopefully, it is clear now.